# Bluegiga iWrap 2.0.2 Pairing issue

Tags: bluetooth, bluegiga

I connected a Bluegiga 2022 chip (iWrap 2.0.2) to the PC serial port and this working fine.

When I send the pairing command ( SET BT PAIR ) then the answer "SYNTAX ERROR" always. I think I send the right command and the device exists.

I think this is a bug in bluegiga or what can I do? Very thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  the correct command is just PAIR MAC address - so something like
PAIR 00:01:90:e6:60:be

TO clear any pairing, type in SET BT PAIR *

The latest iWrap is now v5 or v6.